# Create Vertex only if "from" and "to" vertex exists

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinnet

I want to create 1000+ Edges in a single query.
Currently, I am using the AWS Neptune database and gremlin.net for creating it.
The issue I am facing is related to the speed. It took huge time because of HTTP requests.
So I am planning to combine all of my queries in a string and executing in a single shot.

```
_g.AddE("allow").From(_g.V().HasLabel('person').Has('name', 'name1')).To(_g.V().HasLabel('phone').Where(__.Out().Has('sensor', 'nfc'))).Next();
```

There are chances that the ***"To"*** (target) Vertex may not be available in the database. When it is the case this query fails as well. So I had to apply a check if that vertex exists before executing this query using hasNext().

So as of now its working fine, but when I am thinking of combining all 1000+ edge creation at once, is it possible to write a query which doesn't break if ***"To"*** (target) Vertex not found?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at using the [Element Existence pattern](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence) for each vertex as shown in the TinkerPop Recipes.

In your example you would replace this section of your query:

```
_g.V().HasLabel('person').Has('name', 'name1')
```

with something like this (I don't have a .NET environment to test the syntax):

```
__.V().Has('person', 'name', 'name1').Fold().
coalesce(__.Unfold(), __.AddV('person').Property('name', 'name1')
```

This will act as an Upsert and either return the existing vertex or add a new one with the name property.  This same pattern can then be used on your To step to ensure that it exists before the edge is created as well.

Comment: I don't want to create a vertex if not exists. I just want to create edge if both vertices exist otherwise simply skip it. and this also I want to create such query for multiple vertices and execute at once.

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple edges from the same start/end location or will the start/end locations change between edges?

Comment: Start location will be same, but End location will be changing.